# How do I update a campaign without it creating a new campaign?

Tags: solidity, web3js, react

I'm working on the update campaign feature in a project.

#### First Issue - Prefilling the form fields

I want first to prefill the form fields then from there, a user can change what they want.
In the `/pages/UpdateCampaign` page, I'm consoling the `state` and it returns all the fields. I've tried setting each item as the default so they will prefill but it's not working.
Any ideas?

#### Second Issue - Updating the campaign instead of creating a new one.

Despite the data not prefilling, I decided to try out the update feature but instead of updating the campaign with its pID, it created a new campaign.
I suspect it's an issue with the `updateCampaign` function in my `web3/contracts/CrowdFunding.sol` but can't seem to figure it out.

[My Repo](https://github.com/kihiuFrank/CrowdFunding)

Answer (score 2):

```
  const updateCampaign = async (form) => {
    try {
      const data = await createCampaign({
        args: [
          // items have to be in the order they were the contract inside createCampaign()
          address, // owner of the campaign
          form.name, // name
          form.title, // title
          form.category, // campaign category
          form.description, // description
          form.target,
          new Date(form.deadline).getTime(),
          form.image,
        ],
      });

      console.log("Contract call success!", data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Contract call failed!", error);
    }
  };
```

This is the updateCampaign function in your client. It calls createCampaign on your contract.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. 
I'm however still stuck. When I log state in ```UpdateCampaign.jsx``` I get an object array with all the info. [See Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lb7126ZESEE54Z5K24SDHe45b1IRGUHi/view?usp=drive_link) To get the value of an item, I'm trying  ```state.item``` eg ```state.id``` but I'm getting "undefined". How do I access the data?

Comment: I figured it out. Everything works well now.